# Search by Date doesnt retrive correct data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I make a search function to search field by `Date`, like `DateTo` and `DateFrom`. I create in Model field of `DataTime` Date

```
[Required]
    [Display(Name = "Date and Time")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DateAndTime { get; set; }
```

In Controller I create action for search

```
public IActionResult Index(string search)
        {
            IEnumerable<AdmissionPacients> admissionPatient = _db.AdmissionPacients
                .Include(u=>u.Patient)
                .Include(d=>d.Doctor);


            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                if(DateTime.TryParse(search,out var dateTime))
                {
                    admissionPatient = admissionPatient.Where
                         (x => x.DateAndTime.ToShortDateString() == dateTime.ToShortDateString()).ToList();
                }
            }

            return View(admissionPatient);
        }
```

One think here is If I put date like `1/22/2021` - `01/31/2021`  I didn't get exactly what I expect as uoutput. I expect in output to get three records but I get two records

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kv2R.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ5j6.png)

Any idea guys where the problem could be ? Since I check a couple of think starting from add `.FirstOrDefault()` and using `Select()` but nothink works ?

Comment: Not sure how it's supposed to give you data that has different dates. Your search can only be one date... not a span

Comment: No I have`DateFrom` and `DateTo` and It needs to return date in range which user input but the situation is that I don't get result which I expect

Comment: Your method, `public IActionResult Index(string search)` takes **1** input which is converted to date and matched against existing Datetime in your table. It will produce results based on `(x => x.DateAndTime.ToShortDateString() == dateTime.ToShortDateString())` which will "always be" the rows when `dateTime` **Equals** x.DateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code:

```
if(DateTime.TryParse(search,out var dateTime))
                {
                    admissionPatient = admissionPatient.Where
                         (x => x.DateAndTime.ToShortDateString().Equals(dateTime.ToShortDateString())).ToList();
                }
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me check

Comment: @mersyam asadi Nope, doesnt work. Same situation as before